# pycharm version-control and deployment

Tags: deployment, version-control, pycharm

Use deployment and version control in Pycharm at the same time. I set `Automatic upload` so each time I change my code at local side, it will be uploaded to the server. And I just use git at local side

But I just found that when I change from branches, the code of server side will not change.

Answer (score 0):

in Tools|Deployment|Options you need to uncheck the "Skip External Changes" checkbox